# Autodesk Forge - Viewer getScreenShot - Blank for IOS

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I have a web app with forge extension for making markups and adding screenshots. That works well with Windows and Android Browsers but I don't know why, always Blank screenshot (just 2D) with IOS!

- Desktop browsers (Safari, Chrome,...) -> 2D : OK ,  3D models : OK
- Browsers on Android devices -> 2D : OK ,  3D models : OK
- Browsers on iPhone and iPad -> 2D : **BLANK**!! ,  3D models : OK

**Screenshot function**

`this.viewer.getScreenShot(sizeX, sizeY, blobURL => fetch(blobURL)...`

**results**
[image]

Comment: It sounds like a potential bug in the viewer code. What version of the viewer and iOS are you testing on?

Comment: I just tried the `viewer.getScreenShot` on my iPhone XS, iOS 13.5.1, Forge Viewer version 7.24.1, and the screenshot seems ok: https://imgur.com/a/bTZe8Id.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you were talking about 2D. Let me try that, too.

Comment: 2D works fine, too: https://imgur.com/a/XWnKgDL.

Comment: yes, I have testet, it works with .dwg 2D too. my problem is just with pdf screenshot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshots seem to be working fine on an iPhone XS, iOS 13.5.1, using Forge Viewer version 7.24.1. Here's a [3D screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10HUa.jpg), and a [2D screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhM1G.jpg).

If you're still having issues, please contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, include the iOS version and viewer version, and if possible, your 2D drawing as well. We will not share it with anyone outside of our team.

Comment: Thank you , but  can you please test with a pdf file?

Comment: I see. Yes, I've been able to repro the issue on an iOS device: https://codepen.io/petrbroz/full/yLOezXW. I will report it to the engineering team.

Comment: Btw. here's a quick workaround for you while we're addressing the issue: you can use a new, more performant implementation of the screenshot logic by replacing `viewer.getScreenShot` with `viewer.impl.getScreenShotProgressive`: https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/yLOevyG. According to the engineering team this approach is more performant, and I've also confirmed that it works with PDFs on iOS as well.